# SAFELY_RELEASE in ViewDidUnLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c

is there any difference between the two methods?

```

```
// MACRO FUNCTION

#define SAFELY_RELEASE(__POINTER) { [__POINTER release]; __POINTER = nil; }

// C FUNCTION

void SAFELY_RELEASE(id __POINTER) {
    [__POINTER release]; __POINTER = nil;
}
```

```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The function won't do what you expect it to, because the pointer will have been passed into it by value, rather than by reference.

Imagine this:

```
- (void)method {
   id object = [[NSObject alloc] init];
   SAFELY_RELEASE( object );
}
```

SAFELY_RELEASE gets `object`. It can send it messages, but setting it to nil will not change its value in `method`.

An equivalent function would be:

```
void SAFELY_RELEASE(id *__POINTER) {
    [*__POINTER release]; *__POINTER = nil;
}
```

Then you'd use it by using:

```
SAFELY_RELEASE( &object );
```

The macro has another downside, though: Xcode's refactoring tools will *probably* not be able to change the parameter inside. For instance:

```
@interface Foo {
    NSObject *var;
}

@implementation Foo

- (id)init {
    if (( self = [super init] )) {
        var = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    SAFELY_RELEASE(var);
    [super dealloc];
}
```

If you try to rename var using the refactor tool, you'll probably find that it won't be able to rename the var in dealloc.

Really, unless you have a really good reason to do this you should be using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

`void SAFELY_RELEASE(id __POINTER)` is guaranted to __POINTER be an releasable object.

Both of them is wrong, because `__POINTER = nil;` will have no effects. You should nil it in object (controller)

Answer (score 0):

I was using one of these macros, then I cam across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068578/do-we-really-need-a-safe-release-macro/7525768#7525768).

Makes sense that you don't want to set to nil while in development as you want it to crash on a dealloc reference and not sending it to nil.